# pyspark: sqlContext can read csv file well, but the content of result is empty

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am new in studing SPARK, and I set up a cluster using CDH5.8.3 and Spark 1.6.0 (recompiled, added spark-sql). When I use Pyspark, I can read a csv file using sqlContext, but the file content can't be read. It's empty. How can I fix it?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYBI7.png)

The empty content: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BFH9.png)

The `7daoqi_train.csv` file in HDFS is not empty.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible and verifiable example ?

Comment: pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars "spark-csv_2.10-1.0.0.jar,commons-csv-1.1.jar" --num-executors 8 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 1g；

import pandas as pd；
import numpy as np；
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier；

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext；
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)；
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true',charset='gbk').load('hdfs://master03.hdp.szqxb.com/test.csv')；
train = df.toPandas()； 
print(train)

Comment: Can you please provide sample data? So that issue can be reproducible

Comment: why don't you try `df.show` before you do `df.topandas` and see if table has data or not. and update the question accordingly